A question about my study on physics
I asked yesterday a question about a picture of three diagrams, which showed values of properties of different atoms. A second question got closed because I posted in the wrong section. I read about guidelines that no questions and answers about non-mainstream physics are not allowed here and since the picture I posted is a part of a theory which is non-mainstream physics. Therefore, I can't directly ask about revaluation, which I am not. I am only asking if the picture meets some kind of relevance, an opinion. Is this prohibited?

It is very difficult to understand what you're asking; your question seems to be been reopened.   There's a useful link but you don't like the answer of the Saha equation: the fact that you do not understand it does not make it incorrect.
Because it is correct it's unlikely you can find another correct equation describing the same physics.  You might be able to find different derivations of the Saha equation, but is this what you are asking?

That question is different. The first question I posted got closed and then I deleted it. I am asking if I can post a picture on this platform and ask for an opinion.

well then maybe you can clarify what is the relevance of this meta question?  It is impossible to make useful comments on a post that has been deleted unless you provide a link to said question.

Does this link work? https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14837/

I posted this question twice. Yesterday on physics section and today on meta section. It doesn't belong to meta section that I realized.

Stack Exchange is generally an objective/factual Q&A site. It's unclear what you meant by "opinion" here, but if it's an open-ended opinion, then it's off-topic here for "opinion-based".

I wanted to know if others would agree with the data I have. This site seems to be the one that has a lot of active people, so I would've had my answer quickly.

From what I can see of the two posts (deleted posts are visible to those with >10k reputation + the authors), you dumped a bunch of pictures and asked if they look reasonable. There's no real indication of what it is you've done (for example, assumptions you've made, equations you've used), so it's not possible for someone to understand what you want to know.

I am aware of this. I suppose I will post it again and see if it will be closed. When I posted it the first time, it got closed within minutes and as I've understood, nobody can't comment on a closed post.

comments are allowed on closed posts, but answers are not allowed. I would strongly encourage you to develop an actual question: describe what it is you're doing, what results you would expect & then ask whether it's reasonable or not. Just dumping the pictures on us again will surely lead to another closure.

Yes. I've reposted the original question.

I am only asking if the picture meets some kind of relevance, an opinion. Is this prohibited? Asking for subjective opinions rather than an objective answer makes the question off-topic.
